# При помощи какой библиотеки лучше построить график в android?

Tags: java, android

Учу android, и мне нужно построить графики двух видов в своем приложении. При этом вид этих графиков хотелось бы стилизовать под графики из другого приложения (аналогичного). Графики из аналогичного приложения прилагаю.
Google говорит, что библиотек, которые справились бы с этим, достаточно много: GraphView, AChartEngine, AndroidPlot и т.д. Соответственно, прошу у знающих людей совета, на чем лучше сделать подобное. Разбираться, в принципе, без разницы с какой библиотекой, но не хочется потом переделывать все наново, если окажется, что выбранная библиотека чего-то не умеет.
Кто на чем работает, у кого какие предпочтения? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, новичку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуй самая мощная будет https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться с MPAndroidChart.

Comment: Все замечательно у MPAndroidChart, но кроме одного маленького нюанса: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1453. А без этого 100% повторяемости с приведенными выше картинками не будет. А так первый график уже ожил у меня) Может кто сталкивался, может в последней версии библиотеки уже можно двигать текстовые значения точек?

Answer (score 2):

GraphicView - когда писал минимальные приложения на андроиде, то пользовался ею. В принципе не трудная в изучении. Есть и видеообзоры и документация 
[вот оф сайт](http://www.android-graphview.org)

Answer (score 0):

Можешь попробовать [WilliamChart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart).